# Splitting a list into sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list below

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I want to make 4 lists of 3 elements each like

```
a = [1,5,9]
b = [2,6,10]
c = [3,7,11]
d = [4,8,12]
```

I am a little confused how to approach it.

Comment: Step 1 - try to identify the logic to split the bigger list into smaller  lists. That should give you some idea of what a naive solution might look like

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested list-comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

p = [[a[j + i * 4] for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]

print(p)
```

Which results in:

```
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

So `p[0]` is your first required partition, `p[1]` is the second & so on.